# does pony send response when it fails?

Tags: ruby, pony

i've been using ruby pony gem to send emails
https://github.com/benprew/pony#readme

unfortunately documentation is not as big as i wish, just shows few methods to send email, but seems that doesnt return any message when the mail cannot be sent.

does anyone have this trouble ? so i wish to know if pony was not able to send email to tell the user that couldnt happen.

should i try with exceptions ? i'm new in ruby so i have tiny knowledge to make a decition.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pony can throw exceptions from the Net::SMTP or Mail gems on failure, so you can catch that exception and show the user the error message. See posts [like this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ponyrb/I_b9t__Fs8w) on the Google Group, though details are a bit scarce.